# Number of real solutions for a system of quadratic equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

For what values of non-negative integer $a$ will the system $x^2 - y^2 = 0$, ${(x-a)}^2 + y^2 = 1$ have exactly three real solutions?

I substituted $a$ with some random integers and found that for $+1$ and $-1$ we get exactly three real solutions. Since $a$ is said to be positive, $+1$ should be the answer. Do we have a systematic way to solve this?

I tried solving the second equation by substituting $x = +y$ or $x = -y$ , but it took me no where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, the problem is: when does it happen that the circle centered at $(a,0)$ ($a>0$) with radius $1$ touches both lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$? It should be clear that that occurs if and only if $a\leqslant\sqrt2$ and that the intersection consists of $2$ points if $a=\sqrt2$, of $4$ points if $a\in(0,\sqrt2)\setminus\{1\}$, and of $3$ points when $a=1$.

Comment: This is incorrect. You forgot the intersection between the 2 lines, which the circle crosses if $a=1$

Comment: But other than that mistake, this is the approach I would go with.

Comment: @Dylan I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

since we have $$x^2=y^2$$ we get
$$(x-a)^2+x^2=1$$ this is equivlent to
$$2x^2-2ax+a^2-1=0$$
Can you proceed?
solving this we get
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\left(a\pm\sqrt{2-a^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, but for each value of $x$, won't we have 2 values of $y$?

Comment: yes from $$x^2=y^2$$ follows $$(x-y)(x+y)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that on substituting $x = \pm y$ into the second equation gives us: $$(\pm y - a)^2+y^2=1$$ $$\implies 2y^2\mp 2ay + a^2-1=0$$ Note that this equation is a **quadratic** in $y$ $\implies$ that it can have **at most two real solutions**.

Can you thus conclude the answer to your question?

Comment: I don't think this is enough. Having 2 $y$ coordinates means there can be anywhere from 2 to 4 solution pairs. If you're saying there can never be more than 2 solutions to the original system...